# get JSON key value pair within json object array in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Here is my JSON

```
[  
   {  
      "var5":"item-company-1",
      "asd2":"item-company-1",
      "tie1":"0",
      "cxs1":"481.891px",
      "xcve2":"130.563px"
   },
   {  
      "var5":"item-company-2",
      "asd2":"item-company-2",
      "tie1":"0",
      "cxs1":"481.891px",
      "xcve2":"130.563px"
   },
   {  
      "var5":"item-company-3",
      "asd2":"item-company-3",
      "tie1":"0",
      "cxs1":"481.891px",
      "xcve2":"130.563px"
   }
]
```

How do I read the key and the value?  Keep in mind I might not know the Key.  I tried using...

```
var data = JSON.parse(json);

Object.keys(data).forEach(function(prop) {
  // `prop` is the property name
  // `data[prop]` is the property value
     console.log(prop + " = " + data[prop]);
});
```

However it just outputs

```
0 = [object Object]
1 = [object Object]
2 = [object Object]
```

**EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION**

in PHP I get the following output which is what I'm trying to achieve from javascript

```
0:
var5 => item-company-1
asd2 => item-company-1
tie1 => 0
cxs1 => 481.891px
xcve2 => 130.563px
1:
var5 => item-company-2
asd2 => item-company-2
tie1 => 0
cxs1 => 481.891px
xcve2 => 130.563px
2:
var5 => item-company-3
asd2 => item-company-3
tie1 => 0
cxs1 => 481.891px
xcve2 => 130.563px
```

Comment: Which property should be your key in that object?

Comment: `console.log(prop, " = ", data[prop])`

Comment: @zerkms that just returns the objects not the keys inside each object

Comment: That is correct. I just shown you how to deal with `console.log` when you want to output an object.

Comment: It automatically puts spaces in between items when giving multiple parameters to `console.log`, so it would be `console.log(prop, "=", data[prop])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) has a reviver function that lets you view key/value pairs at it parses:

```js
var data = '[{"var5":"item-company-1","asd2":"item-company-1","tie1":"0","cxs1":"481.891px","xcve2":"130.563px"},{"var5":"item-company-2","asd2":"item-company-2","tie1":"0","cxs1":"481.891px","xcve2":"130.563px"},{"var5":"item-company-3","asd2":"item-company-3","tie1":"0","cxs1":"481.891px","xcve2":"130.563px"}]';

JSON.parse(data, function(key, value) {
  console.log(key, "=>", value);
  return value;
});
```

To iterate just the keys from the objects, use nested loops:

```js
var json = '[{"var5":"item-company-1","asd2":"item-company-1","tie1":"0","cxs1":"481.891px","xcve2":"130.563px"},{"var5":"item-company-2","asd2":"item-company-2","tie1":"0","cxs1":"481.891px","xcve2":"130.563px"},{"var5":"item-company-3","asd2":"item-company-3","tie1":"0","cxs1":"481.891px","xcve2":"130.563px"}]';

var data = JSON.parse(json);

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  console.log(i + ":");
  for (var key in data[i]) {
    console.log(key, "=>", data[i][key]);  
  }
}
```

Comment: `Object.keys` does not work in IE8. `Array.prototype.forEach` does not work in IE8 either. `JSON.parse` does not work in IE7.

Comment: @zerkms That's why we have polyfill libraries

Comment: That's why we have babel.

Comment: @zerkms Babel is too much just for this single operation. Of course people are free to use it.

Comment: I would like to mark this as an answer, but I can't.  Just for the simple reason that some reason 0: is the last thats printed out in its object, also your returning a key value pair that is undefined and doesn't exist in the actual json itself.  Baffled

Comment: @eqiz no it does not, the latest `undefined` comes from the whole `JSON.parse(...)` expression. But I still suggest to not follow this solution: reviver is not designed for simply iterating a json, and you should use normal loops instead.

Comment: @zerkms not sure what you mean.  the last undefined shows up not only in his "run snippet" example, but also on my server in console.log.

Comment: @eqiz It's because the reviver function is also used to map values, so not returning anything means removing it from the output object. This shows all of the key/values, including the key/values from the array

Comment: @eqiz that is what I meant - in your console every statement must return a value. The `JSON.parse` in this case returned `undefined`. It would not happen if you run it in a js file. But still, `JSON.parse`'s reviver is not designed to iterate over a JSON object. For iteration you should prefer just regular loops.

Comment: @4castle I just can't see using that then. In order to use that code, I would have to write an if statement specifically to watch and throw that out.  Wouldn't be feasible.

Comment: @eqiz That's fine, but if this is for debugging purposes, there's not really a problem. I've included the simple for loop answer also.

Comment: @4castle Understandable, I should of been more clear in my post that the intention for the console.log was just to see the data as it was coming out by example instead of trying to create some HTML element to stick it in and make it work in a real life example to extract the actual data.  I marked as answer soon as I saw you put back the nested loop since both are great examples of different ways for both scenarios

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```js
var data = [  
   {  
      "var5":"item-company-1",
      "asd2":"item-company-1",
      "tie1":"0",
      "cxs1":"481.891px",
      "xcve2":"130.563px"
   },
   {  
      "var5":"item-company-2",
      "asd2":"item-company-2",
      "tie1":"0",
      "cxs1":"481.891px",
      "xcve2":"130.563px"
   },
   {  
      "var5":"item-company-3",
      "asd2":"item-company-3",
      "tie1":"0",
      "cxs1":"481.891px",
      "xcve2":"130.563px"
   }
]

for(var i=0,item;item=data[i++];){
  console.log("==========="+i+"=========")
  for(var key in item){
    console.log(key+":"+item[key])
  }
}
```

Comment: @zerkms Thanks,but i want to know what's the reason.Use like this,just want the code simply.

Comment: The reason: there is a third section in `for` designed to modify the loop counter. It is really awkward to see mutable comparison.

Comment: @zerkms Thank you.Have a good way do this? var length =data.length;for(var i=0;i<length;i++) ?

Answer (score 2):

This should work...

```
data.forEach(function(obj) {
  for (let key in obj) {
    let value = obj[key];
    console.log(`Key: ${key}, Value: ${value}`)
  }
});
```

In your implementation, `Object.keys(data)` is evaluating to an array of the numeric keys in the **data** array. So the `prop` parameter in your callback function is not referring to the keys of the objects in the **data** array.

[Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: @zerkms I'm just giving a warning to those who view the answer. People have to check that it fits with their compatibility requirements before they use it. There's nothing wrong with this answer.

Comment: @4castle I think it would be a good lesson to learn about "a thing" before using (see copy-pasting) it, if they break their production :-)

Comment: @zerkms I do too, but this answer hasn't given any indications that they are using newer features, or what those features are called.

Comment: @4castle anyone before using code must read through it and make sure they understand every token from it. But I agree for something as new as ES2015 (which is more than 1y old after the standardisation and almost 2y since first proposals) it might have been noted explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

You actually have array for objects. So Code should look like this

```
var data = JSON.parse(json);
for (var key in data) {
    for (var prop in data[key]) {
        console.log(prop + " = " + data[key][prop]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You never defined `obj`. It should be `data[key][prop]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your code

```js
    var data = [  
       {  
          "var5":"item-company-1",
          "asd2":"item-company-1",
          "tie1":"0",
          "cxs1":"481.891px",
          "xcve2":"130.563px"
       },
       {  
          "var5":"item-company-2",
          "asd2":"item-company-2",
          "tie1":"0",
          "cxs1":"481.891px",
          "xcve2":"130.563px"
       },
       {  
          "var5":"item-company-3",
          "asd2":"item-company-3",
          "tie1":"0",
          "cxs1":"481.891px",
          "xcve2":"130.563px"
       }
    ];

data.forEach(function(obj,k) {
     console.log(k+":");
  // `prop` is the property name
  // `data[prop]` is the property value
     Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key){
     console.log(k+":" +key + " = " + obj[key]);
});
     
});
```